# AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'explore'

Tags: geopandas, folium

I'm trying the same code given in geopandas documentation, but the execution is not successful. I upgraded the geopandas version to 0.10.2 using pip install geopandas==0.10.2, but when I check the version using **version** it is still in 0.9.0  [error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRuLr.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: `import geopandas as gpd` then `gpd.__version__` will give you the actual version you are using.  try `pip install --upgrade geopandas` should work.  Are you using virtual envs and have upgraded in wrong env?

Comment: I upgraded the geopandas as you mentioned. My question is even after upgrading it's not working for me.